SUBSTRING_INDEX Start position
I am trying to use SUBSTRING_INDEX to select a string between 2 values, I need the second delimiter to be the first occurrence after the first delimiter because there are a random number of occurrence of the delimiter
I hope that makes sense
SET @initials := 'appear)","value":"';
SET @initialsE := '"';

SELECT
sales_order_item.product_options,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sales_order_item.product_options,@initialsE,1),@initials,-1) AS 'Name'
FROM
    sales_order_grid
    INNER JOIN
    sales_order_item
    ON 
        sales_order_item.order_id = sales_order_grid.entity_id


I want it to find the string between @initials and the first occurrence of @initialsE after @initials

not clear what you are asking?  please show some sample data and expected results?  and explain how what you tried is not doing what you want

Never mind, I had mixed up
@initials,-1),@initialse,1)' With @initialsE,1),@initials,-1)

if this is json data, you are far better off using JSON_VALUE()

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sales_order_item.product_options,@initialsE,1),@initials,-1) AS 'Name'
Should have been
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sales_order_item.product_options,@initials,-1),@initialse,1) AS 'Name',

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
